# msgpack: haskell & python

Tags: python, haskell, msgpack

I'm confused by the differences between [haskell](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-haskell) and [python](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-python) clients for msgpack.
This:

```
import Data.MessagePack as MP
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL

BL.writeFile "test_haskell" $ MP.pack (0, 2, 28, ())
```

and this:

```
import msgpack

with open("test_python", "w") as f:
    f.write(msgpack.packb([0, 2, 28, []]))
```

give me the different files:

```
$ diff test_haskell test_python
Binary files test_haskell and test_python differ
```

Can anybody explain, what I'm doing wrong? Maybe I misunderstood something about `ByteString` usage?

Comment: Does msgpack care about lists vs tuples? In haskell you're using a tuple (whose last element is unit aka `()`), and in python you're using a list (whose last element is `[]`, the empty list). Try [using python tuples](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm).

Comment: @rampion Result of the python ``packb`` with tuples is the same as for lists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The empty tuple `()` in Haskell is not like empty tuple or empty list in Python. It's similar to `None` in Python. (in the context of msgpack).

So to get the same result, change the haskell program as:

```
MP.pack (0, 2, 28, [])  -- empty list
```

Or change the python program as:

```
f.write(msgpack.packb([0, 2, 28, None]))
```

[See a demo.](http://asciinema.org/a/12315)